# setChildIndex in AS3 set on default index

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an object and for some reason I want to bring it to front when it starts dragging:

```
  myObject.startDrag();
  setChildIndex(myObject, numChildren-1);
```

Now, when I go to next or previous frame, myObject is over other objects.
How I can restore the myObjects index to default value at the begining, after dargged it?

Answer (score 1):

before calling

```
 startDrag()
```

use

```
 var previousIndex = getChildIndex(myObject);
```

after dragging is finished then set the index of object to previous object.

```
 setChildIndex(myObject, previousIndex);
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: @Amir Make sure you have that var accessible in the other event listener, that means, make it global or attached to object.

Comment: @Paras Mittal You are proposing a local var, while it won't be accessible in another event listener. Otherwise, a good answer.

Comment: Ok, it's accessible but doesn't work! I think that my solution is when I press next or back button, set myObject visible to false!

Answer (score 0):

First store default object index. Suppose myBox is your display object.
Now you can set default index of object when you want.

```
var originalIndex = this.getChildIndex(myBox);

myBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown);
myBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp);

function onDown(e:MouseEvent)
{
     //Set object index on top
     this.setChildIndex(myBox,this.numChildnre-1);
     myBox.startDrag();
}

function onUp(e:MouseEvent)
{
     myBox.stopDrag();

     //Set object index as originalIndex
     this.setChildIndex(myBox,originalIndex);
}
```